# How to send Parameters between spring controller methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a resetPassword.jsp form which posts to resetPassword method and request is redirected to updateNewPassword method as below

Am using jdk 7 and spring MVC 4

```
@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public ModelAndView resetPassword(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
    getCurrentRequestProperties().put(CurrentRequestProperties.IS_VALID_REQUEST, true);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    String hStrCallback = request.getParameter("hString");
    UserSecurityQuestions qRecord;
    if (qRecord.equalsAnswer(1, ans1) && qRecord.equalsAnswer(2, ans2)) {
            RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("/updateNewPassword.do");
            rd.forward(request, response);
            mav.setViewName("updateNewPassword.do");
    }
    mav.addObject("notimeout", true);
    return mav;
}

@RequestMapping(method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public ModelAndView updateNewPassword(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
    getCurrentRequestProperties().put(CurrentRequestProperties.IS_VALID_REQUEST, true);
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
    String hString = request.getParameter("hString");
     String newPassword = request.getParameter("newPassword");
    String confirmPassword = request.getParameter("confirmPassword");
    if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(newPassword) || StringUtils.isNotEmpty(confirmPassword)) {
        UserSecurityQuestions qRecord = api.search.query(UserSecurityQuestions.class,
                api.search.property("hashString").eq(hString)).first();
        if (qRecord != null && !qRecord.isValidRequest()) {
            mav.addObject("failedMessage", "forgot.url.expired");
        } else 
        {
          // updates the password
         }
        } else {
        mav.addObject("hString", hString);
        mav.addObject("notimeout", true);
    }
    return mav;
}
```

Step1: Here is the workflow, when a password is reset for a user an email is being sent as bwlow
`https://dc-rpall/CP/resetPassword.do?hStr=50585030a9ae6cb4` when a user is clicked on the URL user gets the resetPassword.jsp with securityQuestions

Step2: Once the user answers the securityQuestions user is redirected to updatedPassword.jsp (request goes from resetPassword method to updateNewPassword method in this step and hString is accessbile here)

Step3: when the user updates password on updatedPassword.jsp and submits it request goes to updateNewPassword method but am getting hString as null in this step even though am adding `hString` to `mav` object in updatedPassword()

Can someone help me how to retrieve `hString` in step 3?

Comment: you are getting hString as null because when request is coming to updateNewPassword() it's a new request and it's not having hString as request parameter.

Comment: Since am adding it to ModelAndView as `mav.addObject("hString", hString);` isn't it supposed to be available in next request?

Comment: but you are setting the hString in mav in updateNewPassword() which is the third step, you need to do the setting in resetPassword().

Comment: In the second step request redirected to updatenewPassword() from resetPassword() and the `if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(newPassword) || StringUtils.isNotEmpty(confirmPassword))` condition is false in updatenewPassword() so request goes to else block and sets the `hString` in mav. In the third step request goes to updateNewPassword() again `if (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(newPassword) || StringUtils.isNotEmpty(confirmPassword))` condition is true and it will update the password

Comment: Is it the url you pass actually identical the one you have appended above? It seems it is hStr in the url but you are trying to retrieve "hString"